# How do I get rid of the "Release 1" in the Page Header of the Sphinx Latex Output?

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, documentation-generation

I'm using the "manual" document class of Sphinx and I'm quite happy with how the Latex Output looks like, except for the page header. It contains the title of my paper, as well as a "Release 1".

Since I'm writing a paper and not a documentation, I clearly don't need the release information. Unfortunately, it is very hard to find information on how to customize Sphinx latex output.

Does somebody know how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To suppress the release info at the top of your Latex output, you need to set the `release` and `latex_elements['releasename']` to empty strings in your `conf.py`. So you might add or modify something like this in `conf.py`:

```
release = ''
latex_elements = { 'releasename': '' }
```

Then the release info will be hidden.

Comment: There will still be a comma in the page header, e.g. "My Project, ".

Comment: It doens't works for me. When i run "make latexpdf" I get something like: title, Release,

Answer (score 1):

As of Sphinx 1.5 something, the workaround of setting an empty string stopped working - at least in my case (I had used it to suppress printing "Release " on the title page) . However, setting release to a blank space does work for me. There's more discussion of it here in the Sphinx-Users group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sphinx-users/L5PUfwVu8f0
and there was a related bug report filed: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/4411

Answer (score 0):

The bellow lines eliminate also the comma in the header. Add them in your `conf.py` file:

```python
latex_custom = r'''
\makeatletter

    \fancypagestyle{normal}{
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{{\py@HeaderFamily\thepage}}
        \fancyfoot[LO]{{\py@HeaderFamily\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
        \fancyfoot[RE]{{\py@HeaderFamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
        \fancyhead[LE,RO]{{\py@HeaderFamily \@title}}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\makeatother
'''

latex_elements = {'preamble': latex_custom}
```

Such a solution affects only the header. 
If you want to remove the release sign also from the front page use the solution provided by ddbeck.

Answer (score -2):

You can use **stopwords** - Stopwords are the words that will not be indexed.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-stopwords

Comment: I'm sorry, think you misunderstood the question. My question is about the Sphinx documentation generator, not the search engine.