# Cannot remove "Release" appearing in sphinx-doc generated pdf

Tags: pdf-generation, python-sphinx

The word **Release** appears on the first page and in pages' headers.

I've commented out *release* and *version* lines in `conf.py` file, but it only removed number of release from the pages.

Is there a way to tell sphinx not to put **Release** in any place of the document?
I must not have it in document I am making.

I have checked sphinx documentation many times and tried to google the case, but I did not succeed.

I have also asked at *#sphinx-doc* at *freenode*, but no one answered so far.

I will supply more details if there are important ones I have missed.

Comment: I have succeeded with achieving result I want with modifying .tex file generated by sphinx. But it is just a hack in my eyes, not the proper solution. I believe sphinx does let to remove that piece of information from the file in it's own config.

Comment: I have already found and answer and I will post it when I will be allowed to. I cannot post answer to my own question earlier, than 8 hours after asking.

Comment: I referred to that question in answer I have given.
Should I mark my question as duplicate?

Comment: You need 250 rep to view and cast close votes on your own questions (http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes). I don't think you need to do anything.

Comment: ok, I get it, thanks. I thoought I should mark it with [duplicate] in topic, but if this has to be voted before, let it be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer in another question, which I couldn't reach before:
[How do I get rid of the "Release 1" in the Page Header of the Sphinx Latex Output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882770/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-release-1-in-the-page-header-of-the-sphinx-latex-outpu)

**ddbecik** has answered the question with following code:

```
release = ''
latex_elements = { 'releasename': '' }
```

So, for saying it literally, I was supposed to put empty string into `release` variable and to add `releasename` directive in the `latex_elements` section, also containing empty string.

It works like a charm, therefore I am sorry for doubling question and I hope it will be easier for other to find answer in future.