# Rinohtype frontend for Sphinx: How to manipulate the PDF subtitle, which is 'Release' by default

Tags: python-sphinx, rinohtype

I'm generating PDFs via the rinohtype extension of Sphinx (i.e. not via the LaTex extension!).

For the two bundled rinohtype templates 'book' and 'article', where the latter is the one I use, the subtitle of the title page always starts with 'Release' by default (and a release version string if one is provided in conf.py via `release = '1.0'` - this is commented out in my case).

I want to:
1a) either get rid of the complete subtitle, i.e. also 'Release' isn't printed on the PDF title page, or
1b) want to change 'Release' to some other String, 'Rev.' in my case;
2) also have the modification of 1a) and/or 1b) applied to the page headers after "front matter", where 'Release' is also the default string.

What I found so far is:

- Here it is described for LaTex, how to hide 'Release' (the subtitle) on the front page. However, this doesnt work for rinohtype. No real surprise, but I gave it a try because rinohtype also interprets some latex settings...
  [How do I get rid of the "Release 1" in the Page Header of the Sphinx Latex Output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882770/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-release-1-in-the-page-header-of-the-sphinx-latex-outpu)
- I also digged into rinohtype stylesheets and I found a way to hide elements of the title page. The linked stylesheet example shows how to hide the date entry on the title page. However, I'm not sure if this is actually the easiest solution (i.e. changing/extending the stylesheet) and this does also not hide the 'Release' String in the following page headers - see my Question 2) above.
  https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/blob/40a63c4e5ad7550f62b6860f1812cb67cafb9dc7/tests_regression/sphinx_minimal.rts

Comment: Sorry, I discovered this question quite late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rinohtype currently does not support changing "*Release*" into something else at the moment. This might be added in the near future however; see issue [#157](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/issues/157). This should also affect the page headers/footers.

You can hide the *Release* subtitle by means of a style sheet, like you discovered. It is also possible to remove it from the page header by supplying a custom [template configuration](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/basicstyling.html#configuring-a-template). You'll need to override the header text for the contents and back matter page templates:

```
[contents_right_page]
header_text = '\t\t{DOCUMENT_TITLE}'

[contents_left_page]
header_text = '{DOCUMENT_TITLE}'

[back_matter_right_page]
header_text = '\t\t{DOCUMENT_TITLE}'

[back_matter_left_page]
header_text = '{DOCUMENT_TITLE}'
```

Comment: After quite some time, I found a slot to really test it and it works like a charm - Thanks!
I also discovered that at least the subtitle part will be covered in the upcoming rinohtype release v0.4.3: see [here](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/pull/182) and [here](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/blob/master/CHANGES.rst). So soon, no need anymore to fiddle with the style sheet in this regard. Great work!